# How to do any number of files in grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to make script which will look for phrase in files. I would like to not specify number of files, where this script will look.

Comment: How will you tell the script where to look, then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but `grep` can take multiple input files, for example `grep foo dir1/* dir2/*.txt`

Comment: I want to look in 2 files, and another time in 3 files for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script will be called like `./script phrase ./file1 ./file2 ...`, then you can use grep within the script like this:

```
grep "$@"
```

This is probably what you want.

---

If your script has options, like `./script option1 phrase option2 ./file1 ...`, then you can use grep within the script like this:

```
grep "$2" "${@:4}"
```

This case uses `2` because *phrase* is argument 2, and uses `4` because the first file is argument 4.

Comment: But I want to give script names of these files.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: ./script.sh phrase <file> <file2> <file3> I want to call this script like that.

Comment: You can use `grep $*` in the script to find *phrase* in all the files. You can also use `${@:2}` wherever you need a list of the files.

Comment: Can you write it down, how exactly it will look like? Is it grep $phrase ${@:2}?

Comment: and option1 what does it mean?

Comment: It's just an example. If you run `./script option1` from the command line, then `$1` in the script will equal the string "option1".

Answer (score 0):

You could put all files that needed to be searched on a directory (ex.: /folder/search/) and then run the following:

```
grep -ri "Phrase to be searched here" /folder/search/
```

That code would look for the phrase to be searched and match the phrase in a case insensitive way (ex.: it would match "Phrase" but and also "phrAse").

Comment: Yes, it will search all files within that folder